# why iterating over unordered_map with unique_ptr forces a pair with a key that is const?

Tags: for-loop, unique-ptr, unordered-map

I found a compiler error that I can not understand why it happens only for std::map with std::unique_ptr.

Assume we have the follow unoredered map object and an iteration code for it:

```
std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<char>> map;

for (const std::pair<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<char>>& item : map)
{
  // do something
}
```

That's compiled well, but if we use unique pointer instead the shared pointer as follows, then we get a compiler error about the iteration pair type:

```
std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<char>> map;
for (const std::pair<uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<char>>& item : map)
{
  // do something 
}

error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' to
 'const std::pair<uint32_t,std::unique_ptr<char,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>
```

Following this error, we can just add 'const' to the key type and it is compiled.

```
for (const std::pair<const uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<char>>& item : map)
                      ^^^
                      |||
```

Why is this compiling error happens just for unique pointer?

Answer (score 0):

A friend gave me the answer and I'm sharing.

The answer lies in the concept of implicit conversion(copy) a compiler is allowed to do.

Lets see the follow simple example:

```
const char  x = 4;
const char& r = x;  // r is reference for x. Checking their addresses yields the same 
                    // address.

const int&  ir = c; // implicit creation of object + conversion(copy). 
                    // ir is different type of x, therefor compiler does implicit
                    //  conversion(copy): it creates behind the scene an object of int, 
                    // convert x into this temporary object. The temporary int object is 
                    // then bound to the reference ir. Checking addresses of ir and x 
                    // yields different addresses because ir is reference of the temporary 
                    // object, not to x
```

So even we use reference - planning for just pointing on an existing object, 
we may actually have an object construction + copy (if the types are different and there is conversion between them).

The same happens in the loop I gave in the question:

```
std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<char>> map;

for (const std::pair<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<char>>& item : map)
{
  // do something
}
```

while the real object held by the map is of type of

```
std::pair<const uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<char>>
```

the loop uses reference of different type:

```
std::pair<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<char>>
```

and therefor, behind the scene, for every iteration, a new temporary object is implicitly constructed and a copy operation for conversion is done.

Not only that it isn't efficient, but it also failed to be compiled when the value is unique_ptr because the conversion does copy and unique_ptr can not be copied.

Thats why using 'auto' may save you such mistakes,

```
std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<char>> map;

for (const auto& item : map)
{
  // do something
}
```

I myself sometimes prefer to play and use the explicit form instead 'auto' in order to face such problems and learn :)